Dynamically change the AWS API Gateway Integration to S3 Put Object or lambda invocation
We have created an AWS API Gateway which is integrated to S3 object put. Such that whenever call is made we save the request body in S3. The response is sent back from integration mapping configuration using velocity template language.
Afterwards, from S3 event bridge triggers the lambda invocation.
Now, we want to directly call the lambda if the size of request body is small and return response directly from lambda and keep the above integration if request body is large.
I guess we are looking for something like a dynamic integration for the API Gateway. Is it possible to achieve that ?

The integration pattern you were asking for is going to be constrained by the maximum size of API gateway (10MB) and Lambda payloads (6MB). What you may want to consider is using S3 pre-signed URLs for uploads which results to direct file uploads from your mobile or web clients to S3. Aside from getting a much larger file upload cap (5GB), you get the advantage of consuming shorter Lambda-function processing time which result to not having to pay for the proxying of the file upload in your functions.
With regards to limiting the size of uploads inside your backend, this is VERY expensive and I'd highly recommend refraining from it as its an inefficient way of validating large uploads. A better approach to this if you have control on the uploading client source code is to check the file size in the browser or in the mobile app before permitting the upload.

There is no web or mobile client. This API is exposed to customer to do their processing directly. While presigned URL is technically good solution, but we are not sure of user experience with that.
